# Cannot acces asp:Label in code behind - Requires object reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

I don't get it. I added an asp:Label in my aspx. page:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="" ID="lblStatus"></asp:Label>
```

then when I try to set the text in the code behind:

```
lblStatus.Text = " test";
```

, it gives me this error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Utilities_MoveFileTemplate.lblStatus'
```

I am trying to set the label's text  in the codehind after a stored procedure has run:

```
 try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    lblStatus.Text = "success";
                }
```

removed "static" keyword and it worked

Comment: This is not code behind that's MarkUp can you show the code where you are using the lblStatus? show the C# code perhaps you are doing something incorrectly.. also try using the this.lblStatus.Text need to see how you are trying to utilize this

Comment: are you having user control on page, i guess in the method in which you are accessing the label it is static method

Comment: Where in the code behind you're trying this: `blStatus.Text = " test";
`. In what method?

Comment: Show your full code behind please.  Also, what is the file name for the aspx page this label is in, and what is the file name for the code behind you're trying to access this label from?

Comment: I've tried this. but nothing shows up

Comment: why don't you show the full method that you are using based on that code snippet.. we need to see what the heck you are trying to do.. who knows how you are trying to use lblStatus "WHAT EVENT ARE YOU DOING THIS CODE...?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are calling a non static property from a static method or in static class. You will need create an instance of Form.

Comment: exactly the same what i wanted to say in my comments +1

Comment: Interesting enough in my other aspx files I never had to make an instance of the label

Comment: for me same case but you don't must have static page or static container

Comment: I just made an instance of the label but intelesence still can't even find the instance ..
public String LabelStatus
{
      get { return lblStatus.Text; }
      set { lblStatus.Text = value; }
}

Comment: add runat="server" to your forms

Comment: <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" ID="lblStatus"></asp:Label>
this is my label and my forms has a runat="server"

Comment: add runat="server" to your forms who contains your controls, your label for example

Comment: Nevermind, I realized what I did wrong. I just took out the "static" keyword from my method and it worked